# Retrieving file value from log4net's config file

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

I'm stuck in a situation where I believe I need to know the name of the log file that the user has specified in logging.xml.  Specifically, I am trying to retrieve the value of the `value` attribute in the `file` element, as shown below ([taken from the log4net docs](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#fileappender))

> For full details see the SDK Reference entry:
>   log4net.Appender.FileAppender.
>        The following example shows how to configure the FileAppender to write messages to a file. The file specified is log-file.txt. The file
>   will be appended to rather than overwritten each time the logging
>   process starts.

```xml
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="log-file.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

When I loop over the appenders with the following code:

```
log4net.Repository.ILoggerRepository repo = LogManager.GetRepository();
foreach (log4net.Appender.IAppender appender in repo.GetAppenders())
{
    FileAppender fa = appender as FileAppender;
}
```

I am unable to find the value "log-file.txt" anywhere in the `fa` object.  Perhaps I have missed it since there are a lot of members and data exposed in the debugger.

Can anyone suggest a way to get at this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileAppender` has property `File` which contains path to the file that logging will be written to. But before you start looking for this property, verify `Name` of appender - you can have several `FileAppenders` configured.

Also keep in mind that `RollingFileAppender` also matches condition `appender is FileAppender`, because it is derived from `FileAppender`.

```
string file = repo.GetAppenders()
                  .OfType<FileAppender>()
                  .Where(fa => fa.Name == "FileAppender")
                  .Single()
                  .Name;
```

Comment: I already looked at the File property, and while I would expect it to say "log-file.txt", instead it basically has "c:\\path\\to\\log\\folder".  If what you say is correct, then perhaps this is a sign that my code touched the repository prior to the method I'm debugging, and has screwed with the File property.

Comment: small correction, File is actually set to "c:\\path\\to\\application\\executable", and not the folder where I want to store the log files.

Comment: @Dave looks like you have modified path (it is assignable). By default path should be equal to `exeDirectory/logFile`

Comment: I thought I had it all figured out, but for some reason when I call GetAppenders, I occasionally get different results.  Although I'm loading the same logging.xml configuration file each time, sometimes I have all 8 appenders, and other times I only have 5.  Sometimes the file name is at the end of the path of the File property, and other times it's not.  Weird!

Comment: ugh, never mind, user error.  I had switched to another project and that one had a different logging.xml file, so that's why the filename disappeared.  Thanks for your input.